# Box2d & Libgdx Contact listener and inactive Bodies

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

Im working on a project with libgdx, box2d, in Java.

**This is what my program does :**

_ when collision between 2 fixtures, set one of the fixture's Body as not 'Active'

```
   myBody.setActive(false);
```

**Problem :**

I noticed that I get a **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1)** in the logcat when I put this line, probably because the inactive body is still in the ContactListener.

I just got 1 ContactListener class in my main program.

How to remove / add a Body to the ContactListener ?
I don't know if this is the solution, but I guess, could you help me ? I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because the contact handling in the listener ocurrs inside the world.step, and the world is blocked while its running.

You can add it to a list for example, for it to be set inactive once the world.step ends.